# About ASP Ad rotator component and IIS version

Tags: asp-classic

ON WHICH IIS DOES ASP ADrotator component run?
How to check IIS version on my computer ?

Comment: On how to check IIS version. Type inetmgr in RUN then on Menubar click Help->About Internet Information Services

Answer (score 0):

Adrotator is installed by default on iis6 (win 2003) but not on IIS7 (win 2008) onwards.  I believe that it's possible to install it on later versions if you can find a copy of the dll